# Spring filter throws custom exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlet-filters

I have a controller advice that handle all validation exception thrown by my application as below.

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class RestApiExceptionController {

    @ExceptionHandler(ValidationErrorException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<?> appNotFoundException(ValidationErrorException exception) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
            .body(new ErrorResponse(exception.getErrorCode(), exception.getMessage())); 
    }
}
```

In my way, I would like to create a filter that will make validation to every request and throw custom exception when necessary. But the thing is that I cannot throw custom exception as show below.

```
public class ValidationFilter implements Filter {
    ...
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
        throw new ValidationErrorException(); // This is impossible
    }
    ...
}
```

How can I throw the ValidationErrorException in this case or there are other better ways to handle such task.

Comment: Yes you can... It just has to be either a `RuntimeException` or a `ServletException`. Also this has nothing to do with Spring but general Servlet API (or even general java programming).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The validations are generally done on the request objects which are in general available in `Controller` layer after they are `transformed` from request format to server processing format. e.g. JSON to Java object.

So the validation should be performed or triggered on `Controller` layer once the request is reached by completing your entire `filter` chaining.

Any validation exception thrown then later on can be handled in your following handler,

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class RestApiExceptionController {

    @ExceptionHandler(ValidationErrorException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<?> appNotFoundException(ValidationErrorException exception) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
            .body(new ErrorResponse(exception.getErrorCode(), exception.getMessage())); 
    }
}
```

The very much `one` of the purpose of `filters` is,

> To intercept requests from a client before they access a resource at
>   back end.

So filters in real don't have the actual resource yet to be validated. They are available once the control reaches to correct `component` and in your case it is `Controller`.

So better approach is not to do any `resource` based validations at `filter` components.

Comment: You are correct. But how about when I need user to attach encrypted secret code to HTTP Header and I would like the Filter to validate every request and throw ValidationErrorException if the secret is not valid?

Comment: @ChhornPonleu again this is more of design decisions. Please look for Spring Security module. You are here trying to do authorization / authentication on request. It has all such security related features available. Also So throw Security exceptions and not validation exceptions.

Comment: It seems like Spring Security has quite more functionalities than what I need. That is why I seek for such very simple solution.