# Spring: How to make a filter throw a custom exception?

Tags: java, spring

I created a filter which authenticate each request header for JWT token:

```
public class JWTAuthenticationFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    private UserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;
    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JWTAuthenticationFilter.class);
    private final static UrlPathHelper urlPathHelper = new UrlPathHelper();

    public JWTAuthenticationFilter(UserDetailsService customUserDetailsService) {
        this.customUserDetailsService = customUserDetailsService;
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        Authentication authentication = AuthenticationService.getAuthentication((HttpServletRequest) request, customUserDetailsService);
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        if (authentication == null) {
            logger.debug("failed authentication while attempting to access " + urlPathHelper.getPathWithinApplication((HttpServletRequest) request));
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

}
```

I want to throw a custom exception, and that exception returns a response:

```
@ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.SOMECODE, reason="There was an issue with the provided authentacion information")  // 409
public class CustomAuthenticationException extends RuntimeException {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6699623945573914987L;

}
```

How should I do this ? What is the best design to catch such exception thrown by filters ? 
Is there any kind of exception handling mechanism provided by the Spring security that I can use and catch everythin in one point ? 
Is there any other way to throw custom exceptions in a filter ?

**Note**: there is another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40987437/spring-filter-throws-custom-exception) which its accepted answer doesn't answer my question. I want to return a response before getting to any controller.

Error cases I want to handle: 
1. Client sends an empty value for the Authorization header.
2. Client sends a malformed token

In both cases I get a response with `500` HTTP status code. I want to get `4XX` code back.

Comment: I guess you didn't read my question to the end. In the last paragraph I explicitly gave a link to that post and said why that question is different.

Comment: But it should be `AuthenticationException` to execute failure handler. I added a few example cases to my question.

Comment: You can do this by adding your custom success & failure handlers, and extend your custom filter from AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter

Comment: @ArianHosseinzadeh which type of exceptions can be thrown in your case?

Comment: `IllegalArgumentException`, `MalformedJwtException`, `SignatureException` are some examples.

Comment: I think all these exceptions should be converted into one generic exception

Comment: I'm going to try extending AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter. will let you know.

Comment: I pass in `customUserDetailsService` to the current `JWTAuthenticationFilter`.  I pass it to `AuthenticationService.getAuthentication` which itself uses it to load the user name (parsed from the token) from the db and get the password to create the authentication token (this happens for each request). I cannot have an argument  for `customUserDetailsService` in the  constructor for a class that extends  `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter`.

Comment: @ArianHosseinzadeh can't you Autowire your customUserDetailsService in your custom filter? or just create getter & setter for customUserDetailsService  in your custom class

Comment: no, it's a filter. and filter is not a @component. therefore autowiring in it doesn't work. let me take another look to see if I can add a getter, setter for it.

Comment: autowiring is working for filter, but you have to create its bean first. Anyway first check whether exception handling working fine or not in filter

Comment: My `JWTAuthenticationFilter` now extends `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter`. There are a few issues. The first issue is that `attemptAuthentication`, `successfulAuthentication` and `unsuccessfulAuthentication` don't get hit, but `doFilter` gets hit. I may ask it in another question. But anything from top of your head ?

Comment: let me give you answer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44043348/abstractauthenticationprocessingfilter-dofilter-gets-hit-but-attemptauthentic

Comment: @Arian Hi Arian- you can autowire in your custom filters as well (although they are not components )

Please find my answer below to see how you can autowire in filters/or places which are not component

Comment: I have used a very simple approach the actual answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76481632/6221192).

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [@ControllerAdvice](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ControllerAdvice.html)

Here's an example from my project.

```
@ControllerAdvice
@RestController
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

    private final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getSimpleName());

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    @ExceptionHandler(value = RuntimeException.class)
    public Response handleBaseException(RuntimeException e) {
        log.error("Error", e);
        Error error = new Error(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.name());
        return Response.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value()).error(error, null).build();
    }

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    @ExceptionHandler(value = NoHandlerFoundException.class)
    public Response handleNoHandlerFoundException(Exception e) {
        log.error("Error", e);
        Error error = new Error(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value(), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.name());
        return Response.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value()).error(error, null).build();
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(value = AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException.class)
    public Response handleException(AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException e) {     
        log.error("Error", e);
        Error error = new Error(ErrorCodes.INVALID_CREDENTIALS_CODE, ErrorCodes.INVALID_CREDENTIALS_MSG);
        return Response.status(ErrorCodes.INVALID_CREDENTIALS_CODE).error(error, null).build();
    }

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)
    @ExceptionHandler(value = UnauthorisedException.class)
    public Response handleNotAuthorizedExceptionException(UnauthorisedException e) {        
//      log.error("Error", e);
        return Response.unauthorized().build();
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(value = Exception.class)
    public String handleException(Exception e) {
        log.error("Error", e);
        return e.getClass().getName() + " 14" + e.getMessage();
    }


}
```

**Edit**

I believe you can response.sendError inside do Filter method.

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    Authentication authentication = AuthenticationService.getAuthentication((HttpServletRequest) request, customUserDetailsService);
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
    if (authentication == null) {
        logger.debug("failed authentication while attempting to access " + urlPathHelper.getPathWithinApplication((HttpServletRequest) request));
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Invalid authentication.");
        setUnauthorizedResponse(response);
        return;
    }
    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
}

public void setUnauthorizedResponse(HttpServletResponse response) {
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    Response unAuthorizedResponse = Response.unauthorized().build();
    try {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println(unAuthorizedResponse.toJsonString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("Error", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Controller advice can only handle exception thrown by controller & services

Comment: I edited my question and added two example cases. For example `MalformedJwtException` and `IllegalArgumentException` where JWT string is empty. I can not have a global exception handler for  `IllegalArgumentException`. It's not always authentication case for such exception. It could be related to other errors.

Comment: Thank you for answering, I would move the EDIT to the top,and I also get `The method unauthorized() is undefined` when calling `Response.unauthorized()`

Comment: Response is own class custom class. You may use your own.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with JWT tokens and posted the solution on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17715921/exception-handling-for-filter-in-spring/46332119#46332119), since the issue there was similar (he had trouble with filter exceptions)

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer: This is not the answer to the question asked, but this is a followup answer to the problem which Arian was asking.**

As commented above, please see how you can autowire in places which are launched before spring container gives us access to beans.

Here I am autowiring my BlacklistJwtRepo

```
if (blacklistJwtRepo == null) { //Lazy Load because filter
        ServletContext servletContext = req.getServletContext();
        WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext =  WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(servletContext);
        blacklistJwtRepo = webApplicationContext.getBean(BlacklistJwtRepo.class);
    }
```

This is where I am getting hold of the req object -

```
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
```

Final code looks like -

```
    @Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;      
    System.out.println("blacklistJwtRepo : " + blacklistJwtRepo);
    //till here the autowired repo (blacklistJwtRepo) is null
    if (blacklistJwtRepo == null) { //Lazy Load because filter
        ServletContext servletContext = req.getServletContext();
        WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(servletContext);
        blacklistJwtRepo = webApplicationContext.getBean(BlacklistJwtRepo.class);
    }
```