# AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter: doFilter gets hit, but `attemptAuthentication` does not

Tags: java, spring

I have the following `filter` definition:

```
@Component
public class JWTAuthenticationFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JWTAuthenticationFilter.class);
    private final static UrlPathHelper urlPathHelper = new UrlPathHelper();


    public JWTAuthenticationFilter() {
        super("/**"); // what should I pass here ? 
        setAuthenticationManager(new NoOpAuthenticationManager());
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {
        Authentication authentication = AuthenticationService.getAuthentication((HttpServletRequest) request, customUserDetailsService);
        return authentication;
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,FilterChain chain, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        super.successfulAuthentication(request, response, chain, authentication);
        logger.debug("successful authentication while attempting to access " + urlPathHelper.getPathWithinApplication((HttpServletRequest) request));
    }

    @Override
    protected void unsuccessfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException failed)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        logger.debug("failed authentication while attempting to access " + urlPathHelper.getPathWithinApplication((HttpServletRequest) request));
    }
}
```

and the following two `configure` methods in web configuration for my Spring security:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter,
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring()                
            .antMatchers("/login**", "/signup**");
}
```

There are a couple of problems with this code:

1. I don't want the filter to exectue when calls are made to `/login` and `/signup` endpoints, but `doFilter` still gets hit even when a call is made to these two endpoints.
2. `attemptAuthentication`, `successfulAuthentication` and `unsuccessfulAuthentication` don't get hit, but `doFilter` does. Why? why these methods are not called ?

What is happening here ? and why ?

Comment: don't override doFilter(), and this will lead to call attempAuthentication() method

Answer (score 0):

Try this(but not tested!):

```
public class JWTAuthenticationFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JWTAuthenticationFilter.class);
    private final static UrlPathHelper urlPathHelper = new UrlPathHelper();


    public JWTAuthenticationFilter() {
        super("/**"); // what should I pass here ? 
        setAuthenticationManager(new NoOpAuthenticationManager());
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {
        Authentication authentication = AuthenticationService.getAuthentication((HttpServletRequest) request, customUserDetailsService);
        return authentication;
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,FilterChain chain, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        super.successfulAuthentication(request, response, chain, authentication);
        logger.debug("successful authentication while attempting to access " + urlPathHelper.getPathWithinApplication((HttpServletRequest) request));
    }

    @Override
    protected void unsuccessfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException failed)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        logger.debug("failed authentication while attempting to access " + urlPathHelper.getPathWithinApplication((HttpServletRequest) request));
    }
}
```

In your configuration file:

```
@Bean("jwtAuthenticationFilter")
    public LoginRequestFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter(){
        LoginRequestFilter filter = new LoginRequestFilter();
        filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
        filter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(successHandler);
        filter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(failureHandler);
        //filter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(failureHandler);
        return filter;
    }
```

and add this as well

```
http.authorizeRequests().and()
                .addFilterAt(jwtAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
```

Comment: This is not a login, thouhg. It's authenticating each request. And I intend to use the methods in the `JWTAuthenticationFilter`. I don't want to define new classes to handle success or failure cases.

Comment: @ArianHosseinzadeh ok, don't register your success or failure handler, just do whatever you want in success & failure handler methods. These methods will only invoke whenever AuthenticationException occurs in attemptAuthentication() method

Answer (score 0):

> 1. I don't want the filter to exectue when calls are made to /login and /signup endpoints, but doFilter still gets hit even when a call is made to these two endpoints.

While I can't explain the relationship betweeh the two `configure()` methods you've written, you can remove `configure(WebSecurity)` and include all path expressions in `configure(HttpSecurity)`, like this:

```
    .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/login", "/signup")
        .permitAll()
        .and()
    .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/**")
        .authenticated();
```

> 2. attemptAuthentication, successfulAuthentication and unsuccessfulAuthentication don't get hit, but doFilter does. Why? why these methods are not called ?

`AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter()` would normally invoke your overridden `attemptAuthentication()` (and other methods, as appropriate).  Your overridden implementation effectively turns this filter into a "no op" by handing the request down to the remainder of the filter chain unconditionally.

Answer (score 0):

Probably too late, however, I've given this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68078924/spring-security-custom-usernamepasswordauthenticationfilter-not-replacing-defaul/75334292#75334292) to a similar question, so it can also be useful here:
Your custom implementation extends the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter (which in its turn extends the AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter). The UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter, by default, is used for .formLogin authentication, handling the default AntRequestMatcher "/login". If you use a different protected endpoint, the filter's attemptAuthentication() method never gets action. So, if you want to use a different matcher (a different protected endpoint), you have to override the default AntRequestMatcher. For instance, you can do so within your custom filter constructor, by using something like that:

```
super.setRequiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/auth/signin", "GET"));
```