# Spring security custom UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter not replacing default UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to implement my own UsernamePasswordAuthenthicationFilter that authenticates every request from my frontend using firebase auth.

```
public class FireBaseAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {
    
    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException { 
        
        .
        .
        //Assigning roles happens here
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
        if (user.getCustomClaims() != null) {
            if (user.getCustomClaims().get("boss").equals("true")) {
                authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("boss"));
            }
            if (user.getCustomClaims().get("admin").equals("true")) {
                authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("admin"));
            }
            if (user.getCustomClaims().get("office").equals("true")) {
                authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("office"));
            }
            if (user.getCustomClaims().get("warehouse").equals("true")) {
                authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("warehouse"));
            }
            if (user.getCustomClaims().get("store").equals("true")) {
                authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("store"));
            }

            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user.getEmail(), user.getUid(), authorities));

   
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
            user.getEmail(),
                user.getUid(),
                authorities
        );
    
            }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

}
```

Then i try and replace the default auth in my security config:

```
public class ApplicationSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().disable().csrf().disable().httpBasic().disable().formLogin().disable()
                .addFilter(new FireBaseAuthenticationFilter())
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS).and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
}
```

But for some reason my custom filter is never called during runtime? What am I missing here?

Comment: Your authentication shouldn't happen in a filter you should provide a custom `AuthenticationProvider`. If you want to replace the filter use one of the other `addFilter` methods else it will be added at the end of the chain.

Comment: I see, so i should move all my code in the firebaseauthenthicationfilter into a custom authentication provider? How would I then set that to be used to authenticate every request?

Comment: You still can use a filter to crate a custom `AuthenticationToken` which is what the `AuthenticationProvider` uses to do authentication. But doesn't it just provide OAuth2 integration? That can be setup without any custom code.

Comment: I'm trying to authenthicate using firebase, so my frontend logs in the user using the firebase sdk. They then send a firebase JWT as a bearer token in every request. All I have to do in the backend is call one firebase function to check if the token is valid, if not throw a 401. I'm new to this so i'm pretty much just going trial and error here, if you have a better solution please by all means correct me.

Comment: So basically you are doing JWT authentication then. If that is just a username/password login, you can just use the regular filters (just need a JWT decoding one) and a custom `AuthenticationProvider` to authenticate with Firebase.

Comment: But there is no username/password login, thats done separately in the frontend app, Login, Sessions and everything is dealt with in the frontend with firebase auth. All i'm receiving is a JWT on the header of every request, this backend app only has to authenticate that token.

Comment: Then why this filter? If the only thing you need to do is to decode the JWT then why do you even need this filter?

Comment: How else will i extract the JWT from every request?                                               
My current understanding is:                                                                                        1. Application receives HTTP request. 2. The filter extracts the token from the request, and calls a custom authenthicationprovider.  3. authenticationprovider authenthicates the token.

Comment: The JWT should already contain everything. You don't need to authenticate only validate the token.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens I'm just trying to do the section "Verify ID tokens using the Firebase Admin SDK". It's literally one line of code to verify the token being sent on every request.

Comment: Which is what you need to do, then extract the information from the token and put that into an `Authentication`. You don't even need to call `AuthenticationManager` etc.

Comment: Ok so how do I extract the information? Using custom filter?

Comment: Yes, just as you have now, but simpler as you don't need to use the authentication manager. JWT is just a described standard and the are libraries to extract tokens from that.

Comment: I think I'm starting to get it, could you please give me some code samples? even pseudocode would work.

Comment: For anyone who might be interested, please take a look at my post [here](https://blog.devgenius.io/spring-boot-security-configuration-practically-explained-part6-a-deep-intro-to-56ce03860ad). Code examples are also provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example :

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().cors().and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, ChallengeConstant.AUTHORIZE_ENDPOINT).permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, ChallengeConstant.TOKEN_ENDPOINT).permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/*").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/assets/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(new JWTFilter(userService, objectMapper), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }
```

If you want to validate token :

```
@AllArgsConstructor
public class JWTFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JWTFilter.class);
    private final UserService userService;
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String token = httpServletRequest.getHeader(ChallengeConstant.AUTH_HEADER);
        if (token != null) {
            LOGGER.info("The request is authenticated. Performing Token validity");
            String userName;
            try {
                userName = JWT.require(Algorithm.HMAC512(ChallengeConstant.DUMMY_SIGN.getBytes()))
                        .build()
                        .verify(token.replace(ChallengeConstant.TOKEN_PREFIX, ""))
                        .getSubject();
            } catch (JWTVerificationException ex) {
                LOGGER.warn(String.format("Token is not valid. Token: %s", token), ex);
                generateErrorResponse(httpServletResponse, ExceptionResponse.UNAUTHORIZED);
                return;
            }
            LOGGER.info("Token is valid for username: {}", userName);
            try {
                UserEntity userEntity = userService.findUserByName(userName);
                List<GrantedAuthority> authList = userEntity.getAuthorizations()
                        .stream()
                        .map(authorizationEntity -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(authorizationEntity.getAuth()))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(
                        new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userEntity.getUserName(), userEntity.getPassword(), authList));
                LOGGER.debug("User has been found by given username: {} with authorities: {}", userName, authList.toString());
            } catch (NotFoundException ex) {
                LOGGER.warn("User couldn't be found with given username: {}", userName);
                generateErrorResponse(httpServletResponse, ExceptionResponse.NOT_FOUND);
                return;
            }
        }
        LOGGER.info("The request is NOT authenticated. It will continue to request chain.");
        filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
    }

    private void generateErrorResponse(HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, ExceptionResponse exceptionResponse) throws IOException {
        LOGGER.trace("Generating http error response");
        httpServletResponse.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        httpServletResponse.setStatus(exceptionResponse.getStatus().value());
        ErrorResource errorResource = new ErrorResource(exceptionResponse.getCode(),
                exceptionResponse.getMessage());
        httpServletResponse.getWriter().write(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(errorResource));
        LOGGER.trace("Error response is {}", errorResource.toString());
        httpServletResponse.getWriter().flush();
    }
```

I think you can validate in Filter and return error response if it is not valid.

Comment: This works partially, the filter is called correctly and the token is validated, but the roles do not seem to get assigned properly.

Comment: Where do you get roles? I kept them in database so simple authorities are roles and auths

Comment: SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(
                        new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userEntity.getUserName(), userEntity.getPassword(), authList))

Comment: Authlist is role bundle and I set it into security context for spring to recognize roles

Comment: I get the roles by calling the firebase api, i updated my code above, i think SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication is not setting roles properly.

Comment: do you have prefix for roles? Maybe you can disable it. Spring uses ROLE_ prefix

Answer (score 0):

Your custom implementation extends the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter (which in its turn extends the AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter). The UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter, by default, is used for .formLogin authentication, handling the default AntRequestMatcher "/login". If you use a different protected endpoint, the filter's attemptAuthentication() method never gets action. So, if you want to use a different matcher (a different protected endpoint), you have to override the default AntRequestMatcher. For instance, you can do so within your custom filter constructor, by using something like that:

```
super.setRequiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/auth/signin", "GET"));
```