# OncePerRequestFilter unable to set error code different than 404

Tags: java, spring, servlet-filters, error-code

I have a Spring application (not using Spring boot) deployed to tomcat

I'm trying to return error 401 (`HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED`) on specific URLs in given condition using `OncePerRequestFilter` ,

But I keep getting Not found error:

```
Response code: 404
```

My Filter(removed conditions):

```
@Component
public class MyFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyFilter.class);
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Not autorized");           
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
            try {
                PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
                out.write(""); // Empty
                out.flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                logger.error("error filtering", e);
            }
            return; // stop chain
    }    
}
```

I tried using similar code to [previous similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44040703/spring-how-to-make-a-filter-throw-a-custom-exception)

> I believe you can response.sendError inside do Filter method.

**EDIT**

If I just throw an exception instead I get a generic error code 500

```
Response code: 500
```

**EDIT 2**

I'm adding filter inside `onStartup` method overriden `WebApplicationInitializer`'s

```
FilterRegistration myFilter = servletContext.addFilter("myFilter ", MyFilter.class);
myFilter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/myservlet/myendpoint/*");
```

**EDIT 3**

Also my filter in `@Componenet` and its package include in component scan

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "my.parent.pacakge"})
```

Comment: According to the javadoc, you shouldn't attempt to write to the response after calling `sendError` : https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendError%28int,%20java.lang.String%29.

Comment: @Arnaud what's the right way? I tried using code from similar answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44040703/spring-how-to-make-a-filter-throw-a-custom-exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code and it works. Different error codes were getting successfully returned. Although, I wanna point out a couple of things-

1. The method `sendError()` sends the response to the client and also clears the response buffer. So, anything you write after it into the response after that is of no use.
2. Calling `setStatus()` is of no use either. The HTTP response and HTTP response code has already been sent to the client in the above line when you called `sendError()`.

Now, this is my hypothesis why your code is not working for you, but it is for me-

The reason that you might be getting HTTP 404 is that your API is not present. This can be due to a spelling error or maybe due to a simple ignorance like calling your API named `/foo/bar` like `/foo/bar/` i.e. with extra trailing forward slash. I believe that your filter is getting executed successfully and you must be doing something useful there, not the sample code of `sendError()` that you have explained in the question.

Also, when you throw an Exception in your filter, the control does not reach to the API and API lookup does not happen. Hence, the default HTTP 500 response is sent to the client due to the unhandled exception instead of HTTP 404.

Comment: Actually I verified the filter is executed, but as you mention I need to remove `sendError()` can you explain why it works as my answer ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55456982/onceperrequestfilter-unable-to-set-error-code-different-than-404/56268995#56268995

Comment: @user7294900 sendError() method sends the response to the client with the HTTP Status code provided in its arguments. 
When we use sendError(), the lines written below it i.e. setStatus() have no effect. 
Although, when you do not use sendError() and use setStatus() instead, the HTTP status provided in the arguments of setStatus() method are obeyed and it works.
In short, use either setStatus() or sendError().

Comment: Can you explain in detail, what exactly puzzles you? Be descriptive.

Comment: Your answer isn't clear. You say it's working and also it shouldn't work because 2 issues, so how it works in your environment when you don't expect it to return 401?

Comment: The code works.  IT ABSOLUTELY WORKS. I have just suggested improvisations in the code with an explanation. I am editing the confusing words. Also, I gave my hypothesis why the code might not be working for you but it is for me and other users.

Answer (score 0):

It return 401 as expected only if `setStatus` is executed after `out.write`

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
out.write("");
response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
```